# Find the value of: tan(100) + tan(125) + tan(100)•tan(125)

Tags: trigonometry

The question given was - solve all the equations that are possible to solve without a calculator. (This is a part of it) Please try to solve this question (obviously without a calculator) if it's possible. :) thanks in advance.

**All values are in degrees**

Comment: We are mathematicians, how do you even know the value exists ;-)

Comment: Using calculator the answer is 1. I am not able to reach it. :|

Comment: Hence, the answer is 1.

Comment: (-1) for that, Awesome.

Comment: Hint:  What is $\tan 225^{\circ}$, and use the addition formula for tan.

Comment: As a general comment, I would convert the values into radians. Then stare at the trigonometric identities until I can condense the expression into terms for which I know the exact value. Then the answer generally flops out

Comment: 1. But, I don't have the values for 25deg

Comment: Macavity, can I get that formula pls? I have the addition and subtraction formulae only for sin and cos.

Comment: The formula has been posted below by Nicky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\tan(\alpha + \beta)=\dfrac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}$ and $\tan(225^\circ)=1$.

Comment: Thank you. :) The answer is 1.